# Easy to use and learn big data tools for reporting

Tags: php, mysql, olap, bigdata

I try to describe the current situation, so it will be easier what I need.
I'm for the finance team of a web page. There are a lot of data under this project in multiple databases. And the finance team of course wants to follow what happens and when and why. They need different reports of everything. For this purpose a few years ago we created a new Mysql DB dedicated for reporting and we synchronise the required data there.
In that DB we are created denormalised tables dedicated for specific reports, in which the data is aggregated by different fields. We need to do this because running the aggregation on the fly is insanely slow because of the amount of the data (tens or hundreds of millions of rows) and the complexity of the aggregation (sometimes grouping by 4-5 columns) and the different filters.

What hurts a lot is that whenever the finance team needs a new chart or report in most of the cases we need to create a new table and populate it, etc. This is something already hurts, but sometimes they come up with completely legitimate requirements what we can't satisfy.

I'm thinking if it would be possible to use some kind of Big Data or OLAP tool for this purpose, what we can easily introduce into our system to replace our current MySQL DB.

The project is written in PHP, and we are using Amazon Services to host everything.

Comment: This is too vague, and is inviting very subjective answers so it's not a good question for SO

Comment: Sadly I don't have a better place to turn to with this question. I'd use the received answers as a starting point because right now I don't even know where to start

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at imply.io / druid.io (imply.io is an analytics packages setup that is built around druid.io).

We've just started using it and on the project I've used it on so far it's been great. The project aggregates financial transactions from a number of sources and allows them to be reported on. I've created a reporting tool based on Pivot (another part of the imply.io package) and it pretty much allows the non-technical users to quickly create any report they could want with minimal training / documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I had a quick look on the documentation and it looks like that druid is exactly what I need. I'll dig myself into it